# Flutter : How can I do a textfield with chips

Tags: flutter, input, textfield

For an app project, I want to implement a textfield where some words can be transformed into chips. I will analyse the typed words and transform some of them into chips. But I don't find on google how to do that. I found some chips input where the user write after the chips but I need that the user can navigate with cursor into the text field and add some text beetwen the chips. How can I do that ?

Thank's in advance

Comment: So if I understood correctly, use case is that user types words into text field and after writing lets say first word it will get analyzed and change into chip inside text field where user can still write? And by hitting backspace right after chip it will get deassebled to word again? So backspace after "foo" chip will change it to "fo" word?

Comment: Exactly. In fact, I will use Google Natural Language to analyse text and transform some words or group of words into chips.

Comment: This sounds really hard. To be honest, at first glance I would say it's nearly impossible to achieve such thing on satisfying level. You can't simply put widgets to display by TextEditingController, not mentioning mixing text with widgets.

Comment: Damn ! I really wanna to do that. Is there no way to do it ?

Comment: How about editing the textfiled decoration so the typed text looks like in a chip

Comment: I want also to put image or icon in the chip and listen for tap, long press...

Comment: may be this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60476222/flutter-allow-user-enter-hashtags

Comment: @JérémyGachon check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155254/how-can-i-build-a-chip-input-field-in-flutter